# How to get date and time in this format?

Tags: .net, formatting

Please let me know how can I can get the current date and time in this format:

> Friday, November 18, 2011 7:00 PM

Comment: The answer can easily be found in the manual for `String.Format()`, which also links to various pages with [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).

Comment: And so what ? downvoting will teach him that all this information is contained in MSDN, under the String.Format() section ? No it won't. With all the answers he's had, he knows how to do it, and where to search in MSDN. What seems evident to you isn't for everyone, especially novices. Downvoting is for BAD questions. Not simple questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
string text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Mind you, you may well want to use one of the [*standard*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) date/time format strings instead of a [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) one like this. This is fundamentally a *human-readable* form, which should usually take account of the culture of the user it's going to be displayed to.

As dahlbyk mentioned, `InvariantCulture` is usually for machine-to-machine formatting, like custom format strings, which is why I've used it here. If this *is* for human consumption but you always want it in US English, then you should specify a US culture. You *may* still want to specify the custom format string instead of using a standard format string if you want to make it clearer in your code (or simpler to change) later. But you really *ought* to work out whether this is meant to be used by humans or machines.

Comment: To reiterate, `InvariantCulture` really shouldn't be used as a stand-in for `en-US`.

Comment: I get this for asking this question"Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more."  what to do now?

Comment: @EhsanKayani: Only what it says on that page, really.

Answer (score 10):

If `CurrentCulture` is `en-US`:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("f")
```

Otherwise you can specify the culture:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("f", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))
```

Or you can use a custom string, which again will depend on culture for month/day names and 24-hour time.

I would not recommend using `InvariantCulture`, which is designed for machine use.

- [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)
- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
string date = someDate.ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt");
```

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) is your friend. This explains all about format strings for DateTimes.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, MMMM, dd, yyyy h:mm tt");
```

Which can be compressed as

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("F", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 4, 10, 6, 30, 0);
 Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("F", 
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));
```

Should display

```
Thursday, April 10, 2008 6:30:00 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.Now.ToString("f");`

Here is a list of all of the [ToString()](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm) patterns.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy hh:mm tt}", dt);
```

Comment: Close, but this will produce a two digit hour.